# How to unescape html special characters in Java?

Tags: java

I have some text strings that I need to process and inside the strings there are HTML special characters. For example:

```
10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;
```

I would like to convert those characters to utf-8.

I used org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4 but didn't have any luck. Is there an easy way to deal with this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "didn't have any luck"? What was the result?

Comment: The same exact characters were returned, none of the html special characters were unescaped

Comment: You may need to roll your own translator. The specific piece is NumericEntityUnescaper in the Apache Commons package. There are recipes for creating your own translator at their site.

Answer (score 6):

[Apache commons-text library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/) has the [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html) class that has the [`unescapeHtml4()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4(java.lang.String)) utility method.

```
String utf8Str = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(htmlStr);
```

You may also need [`unescapeXml()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml(java.lang.String))

Comment: I already tried using that library, the special characters were not unescaped.

Comment: Try `unescapeXml()` too

Comment: @Bohemian Many thanks! This is how I preserved `>` literal in strings.

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils` from Apache commons-lang is deprecated. We now have to use the same class from Apache commons-text.

Comment: @Thomas thanks. Answer and links updated.

Answer (score 0):

@Bohemian 's code is correct, It works for me, your un-encoded string is 1010.

Now, I'm adding another answer instead of commenting on Bohemian's answer because there are two things that still need to be mentioned:

1. I copy-pasted your string into HTML code and the browser can't render your characters properly, because your String is incorrectly encoded, i. e. the string has encoded the high surrogate and the low one for two-bytes-chars separately, instead of encoding the whole codepoint (it seems the original string is a UTF-16 encoded string, maybe a Java String?).
2. You want the string to be re-encoded to UTF-8.

Once you have your String unencoded by `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(htmlStr)` (which un-encodes your string successfully despite being encoded incorrectly), it doesn't have much sense talking about "string encodings" as java strings are "unaware" about encodings. (they use UTF-16 internally though).

If you need a group of bytes containing a UTF-8 encoded "string", you need to get the "raw" bytes from a String encoded as UTF-8:

```
String javaStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(htmlStr);
byte[] rawUft8String = javaStr.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

And do with such byte array whatever you need.

Now if what you need is to write a UTF-8 encoded string to a File, instead of that byte array you need to specify the encoding when you create the proper `java.io.Writer`.

Try this code to un-encode your string (change the file path first) and then open the resulting file in any editor that supports UTF-8:

**java.io.Writer approach (better):**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String str = "10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;";

    String javaString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str);

    try(Writer output = new OutputStreamWriter(
            new FileOutputStream("/path/to/testing.txt"), "UTF-8")) {
        output.write(javaString);
    }
}
```

**java.io.OutputStream approach (if you already have a "raw string"):**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String str = "10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;10&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde2d;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde22;&#xd83d;&#xde02;&#xd83d;&#xde02;";

    String javaString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(str);

    try(OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/testing.txt")) {
        for (byte b : javaString.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))) {
            output.write(b);
        }
    }

}
```